# The text "height" keeps popping up in tables

Tags: tables

In my LaTeX document, I have some simple code for the simplest of tables. 
But, when I let TeXnicCenter output it to PDF, the text 'height' is suddenly in the first cell and on the first cell in a new row I didn't define. 
Of course googling for the height and table gives lots of results, but not to this question

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        ~ & $\theta$      & d   & a  & $\alpha$ \\ \hline
        1 & 0             & 100 & 0  & $\pi$    \\ 
        2 & 0             & 0   & 90 & 0        \\ 
        3 & $\frac{\pi}{2}$ & 50  & 0  & 0      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem (_i.e._ not just the table, but the preamble too).

Comment: Interestingly, I have repro'd this behaviour when using \notag \hline, but not with \hline \notag.  I may try to write up if I can diagnose the problem properly, but for now leaving comment in case anyone runs across this in searching and it may hel a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you must have something like the following in your code, where you have `height` instead of `\hline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
        height
        ~ & $\theta$      & d   & a  & $\alpha$ \\ \hline
        1 & 0             & 100 & 0  & $\pi$    \\ 
        2 & 0             & 0   & 90 & 0        \\ 
        3 & $\frac{\pi}{2}$ & 50  & 0  & 0      \\
        height
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The above produces the output you provided. With `height` in the above replaced with `\hline` (as per your MWE), I get the following. So, your MWE is correct, but check your actual code.

[image: Result]

Comment: If that is not the case, try `\show\hline` in the tabular. It should stop the compilation and give the following message:
``> \hline=macro:
->\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet \reserved
@a \@xhline .`` If it says something else (especially `height`), `\hline` has been redefined somewhere.

Comment: @Stephen: I thought of that, but the `\hline` on the second line seems to have worked so don't think that is the case.

Comment: Somehow, pasting in your code, with the 'height' text included, then replacing that by \hline works... I completely los on why that woudld happen, because the code is now again exactly as before, how I posted it in the original question.

Comment: Maybe you have some active unicode character in it, which causes trouble.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Ah, right, I missed that one `\hline`!